# Adding Subscriptions to Windows Phone app as an in-app purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase, windows-phone

From my understanding, Windows Phone now allows in-app purchases. I would like to empower my users to signup for one-of-three subscription levels within my app. However, I do not understand how to enable this type of scenario. I see the option to add an "In-app product". However, in my case, I'm not sure of the following:

- Am I offering one product or three separate products (one for each subscription level).
- I don't understand the "Product Identifier" is this an identifier for the subscription or the identifier of my app? If its the former, shouldn't I just toss a GUID in here?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be worth taking a look at [the overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206949%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) - your product identifier is the one you submit (as a person) via the development dashboard - it's also the one that your app can enumerate to see the list of available products, and the product id you'd use to purchase.

As far as I'm aware, you cannot have products that are (for example) £10 *per month* though - of course you could do something like have bundles on a pricing structure that exchange for something within your app, maybe £5 for 5 music downloads, £9 for 10 etc. rather than "a £10 per month for unlimited" (difficult to give a generic example though)